# Get all itemprop and itemprop depths

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I have this code and it works more or less, the problem is some of them are empty and in wrong place in the array, and inside offers there's 3 other itemprops.

I dont want to hard code because I'm going to use it on multi websites.

```
function get_product_itemprop($url){
$url = file_get_contents($url);
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop]'); 

$new_data = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) { 
    $new_data[$node->getAttribute("itemprop")] = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$node->nodeValue));
}
return $new_data;

}
```

Result of the function

```
    array(8) {
  ["breadcrumb"]=>
  string(38) "Home Atomizers & Coils Amor Mini coils"
  ["name"]=>
  string(15) "Amor Mini coils"
  ["sku"]=>
  string(5) "CO815"
  ["offers"]=>
  string(8) "$ 13.99"
  ["price"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["priceCurrency"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["availability"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  }
```

On http://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool I get all the itemprops and I want a similar structure they done but with an array:

[image: http://imgur.com/KbNRvnG]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Please be specific about what you want us to help you with. Don't include links to images, rather add the image instead. Eventually see this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the [`attributes`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes) property:

```
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        $new_data[$attr->nodeName] []= $attr->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

### Example

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<html>
    <body>
        <div itemprop="10" a="20" b="30"></div>
        <div itemprop="40" a="50" z="60"></div>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($d);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop]');


$new_data = [];
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        $new_data[$attr->nodeName] []= $attr->nodeValue;
    }
}
var_dump($new_data);
```

*Output*

```
array(4) {
  ["itemprop"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "40"
  }
  ["a"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "20"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "50"
  }
  ["b"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "30"
  }
  ["z"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "60"
  }
}
```

The sample code fetches all elements in the document having `itemprop` property. If you want to fetch all elements with properties, use `@*`, e.g. `//*[@*]`.

Comment: Nice that worked, but the keys are in a different array now http://imgur.com/I4kf9T1.jpg

Comment: @rakma, you haven't specified the expected output, so I composed it myself. The general idea, however, is iterating the `attributes` property.

Comment: each site has different names on itemprops and some include rating etc, if u can get the keys to stick with the values im happy

Comment: all itemprops on the sites is similar to this html code 
<itemprop="price" content="13.99">

Comment: @rakma, still it is unclear. You should provide sample input and output in the question, just as in my example. By the way, the code in the question is not quite a [mcve]

Comment: Html is on this sites

subohm.com/vape/e-liquid/ruthless/ez-duz-it-on-ice/
greyhaze.co.uk/products/convsr-brass-by-league-of-scoundrels

Output (this is the array i want by fetching itemprop)

      array(8) {
        ["name"] => Somename,
        ["sku"]  => d29844,
        ["price"]  => 15,99,
        ["priceCurrency"]  => USA,
        ["availability"]  => InStock,
        ["url" => http://urlhere,
        ["aggregateRating"] => 4,
        ["ratingValue"] => 'blablabla',
        ["bestRating"] => 5,
        ["ratingCount"] => 5,
        ["reviewCount"] => 10,
      }

Comment: Thanks for the help, i trashed the code and im now using Goutte from github